# List entries for a single tag from blog section

Tags: templating, tags

I want to get a list of entries in a template that have one specific tag 'weddings' and exclude entries that do not have this tag.

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.search('weddings').first() %}

{% if tag %}          
  {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag) %}
  {% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog').limit(5) %}
    {# get stuff #}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But this gets me all blog entries - even those without the Tag weddings. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Luke's](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/15673/57) answer is correct.  Your issue is that you have two tag groups defined (`default` and `blogTags`) and you happen to have a `weddings` tag defined for both groups.

The Tag field you have in your `blog` section has it source limited to the `blogTags` tag group, so you need to be explicit about which tags you want to pull from because of the duplicate tags.

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.group('blogTags').slug('weddings').first() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag) %}
```

Comment: thanks Brad and Luke - so darn obvious in the end. Much appreciated support

Answer (score 4):

You were very close! You are looping through `craft.entries.section('blog')` which doesn't use your tag query. You simply need to loop through the results of your query which you've set in the `entries` variable.

You may want to grab your weddings tag using the tag's id or slug as `.search` will find any tag with the string 'weddings' in it.

It might also be a good idea to use the conditional to check `entries` is returning something first, before outputting it.

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.slug('weddings').first() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag) %}

{% if entries|length %}
  {% for entry in entries.limit(5) %}
    {# get stuff #}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks Luke - thats not working for me - i get zero results.....

Comment: Try using `.title` instead of `.slug` and change 'weddings` to the tags Title.

Comment: Mmm something is not right here. The title is 'weddings' lowercase.  I noticed that some tags were 'wedding flowers' and read something about spaces causing issues in tags..so deleted tags.and re added...but still getting nothing

Comment: `.title` and `.slug` will only return absolute matches. If you want to return any tags that include 'weddings' then you'll need to use `.search` just you were to begin with.

Comment: Still i get nothing output....Mmm gonna call Brandon direct!

Comment: What have you tried to debug so far? Have you tried seeing if `tag` is an element? Does `entries|length` return more than 0?

Comment: HAHAHA - "**going to call Brandon direct!**" That should be on a T-Shirt :)

Comment: Once you've applied `entries|length`, you made Craft query for the entries and `entries` is now either null or an array of entry models. Both do not have a `limit()` method and the code should throw an error at this line. At least with devMode enabled.